# How to pass convert string code of python to R using reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have function in python as following :

```
def print_hello():
    print("hello")
```

Rather than writing to python file and reading it from file using `source_python`. I would like just pass function as string and convert into R.

similar to following things

```
library(reticulate)
myPythonFunction <- "def print_hello():
     print("hello")
"

source_from_string(myPythonFunction)

print_hello()
```

Does reticulate package has this function ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `py_run_string` to execute the module and the function 'print_hello' is called from the python env by `py$`

```
library(reticulate)
myPythonFunction <- "def print_hello():
                         print('hello')"
py_run_string(myPythonFunction)
py$print_hello()
#hello
```